# Checking whether element appears on page after form is submitted to check whether user has logged in

Tags: jquery

I have a login form and want to check that a function is called only if a user fails to log in, else that function isn't called. I want to do this just using Jquery by checking whether an element exists on the page. For example, if they've not logged in successfully, the login form will still be there on the page. If they have logged in successfully, it will not appear as they'll be directed to the home page. Here is my code so far:

```
    $(document).on("submit", "#myForm", function (e) {

           if ($('#myForm').length) {

               alert("hello");
               // Call Function 

           }
    });
}

$(document).ready(Login);
```

I am trying to use `($('#myForm').length)` to see if the login form still exists on the page and, if it does, I will call the function I want to call. However the issue is that this is called no matter what (tested with the `alert`).

Can anyone advise me how  I can wait for the page to be loaded after the form is submitted so that only THEN does my code check to see whether the login form exists on the page? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code, just set some `bool` key in sessionStorage and set it to `true` on submit, and check on page load if this value is true and form still exists...here my code doesn't work because of on jsfiddle I don't have access to `sessionStorage`, try it on your project.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  const form = $('#my-form');
  const isTried = window.sessionStorage.getItem('triedToLogin') || false;
  if (isTried && form.length) {
    alert("hello");
  }
  
  if (!form.length){
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('triedToLogin', false);
  }
  
  form.on('submit', function(){
      window.sessionStorage.setItem('triedToLogin', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my-form">
<input placeholder="login" type="text" name="login"/>
<input placeholder="password" type="password" name="password"/>
<button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @IvanKaraman - do I need to clear the sessionStorage at any point? What happens if I log in, log out and then make a failed login attempt?

Comment: it clears when the browser tab closing, but you can set it to false when the user is logged in, because if user click log out and then loads form, message will be shown, I add  else condition to set `false` if a page loaded and form don't exist and the user didn't try to login, sorry for my bad eng...

Comment: Thank you @IvanKaraman - how do I set it to false when the user has logged in? Can I just add `window.sessionStorage.setItem('triedToLogin', false);` after `window.sessionStorage.setItem('triedToLogin', true);` ?

Comment: @Jordan1993 yes

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did try this, but when I log in successfully and then log out again, I receive the same 'hello' alert as at that point in time the 'triedToLogin' is still in the sessionStorage.

Comment: thanks again Unfortunately the same thing happens, and for some reason the alert pops up twice :S

Comment: @Jordan1993 can you explain how is your login works?

Comment: you can see it twice only if the page reloads twice

Comment: Sure - so when a user logs in with correct username and password they're taken to home page. If not, they stay on the login page as the login failed.
From the home page, if they click log out, this will take them back to login page.

Comment: @Jordan1993 the page reloads on fail? Try to close this tab, and open another one and test again

Comment: the page reloading twice was my fault, sorry, I just realised I was accidentally calling it twice in the code.

As for the alert, if I successfully log in, I get directed to the home page. Then I click log out, which takes me back to the login page, where the alert pops up again. I need to somehow clear the session in between this, if this makes sense? Sorry, I am probably not explaining this very well!

Comment: you can set to false this key in session storage on click 'log out'